# How to remove highlight of button onclick

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When a button is clicked, for a fraction of second it gets highlighted in  the theme color set by user for the windwos phone device.What method should be called to over ride this behaviour.I tried using  MouseEnter and setting the background as white, but it doesnt work,

```
       System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush whiteBrush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        signIn.Background = whiteBrush;
```

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the place where you need to do the edition . Change the pressed tag accordingly

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage ...>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Cyan" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Background="Black">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Button Content="Button" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Add it to page and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465498.aspx). This allows you to use the VisualStateManager and control what your control looks like during any point of display (Normal, Hovered, Pressed, Focused). [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278069%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is pretty verbose on the topic.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use click event just use `MouseLeftButtonUp` and `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

when you press button at that time `MouseLeftButtonDown` event is fire so in this method you an change color of button using

```
System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush whiteBrush = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        signIn.Background = whiteBrush;
```

And in `MouseLeftButtonUp` event you can set your normal button color

Hope it will work for you.